# adding a html (with scripts) file into a div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to js and I'm having difficulties loading a html page inside a div. I use the foundation framework and I have a begin page (i.e. the first page people see when they visit my web). There's a button on that page and when that button is clicked on it should load a html document. So far so good. The problem is that the html file loads but the js scripts that it uses don't. I've tried it many times but I just can't figure it out.

I've tried loading the script first in the index.html file,
-loading the scripts in the index.html file and the ok.html(the subscription form) file
-load the scripts only in the ok.html file.

My thoughts:
I think the problem is that in my .js file I'm using `document.ready`, but I'm not sure.

I appreciate your help/feedback!

My code for the `index.html` file:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns" id="alt">
    <div class="panel" id="plas" >
      <div class="row">
            <div class="large-9 columns" id="info">
             random text
            </div>
     <div id="inschrijven">

     </div>
          <div class="large-3 columns right">
            <a  href="#"><img src="img/button.png" id="imgz" />
            </a>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>     
</div>
```

Code in the .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#imgz, #zimgz").click(function(){
    $("#plas, #imgz").hide();
    $("#alt").load("ok.html");
  });
});
```

Comment: I think that it has something to do with where your `#alt` lives. Lemme fiddle.

Comment: don't you get any javascript errors on the javascript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it working. Feel free to check the source. Do your files live on the same domain? Could be a `CORS` issue.

All of my scripts (on the loaded `html` page are local).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js'>
```

#### http://sinsysonline.com/testing.html

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_home").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("index.html");
    });
});
```

**Please provide `live code` so we can help debug further if the above is not true.**

Comment: FYI, hover over icons. Those are scripts I wrote utilizing jQuery, so I know it's loading scripts.

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback, it works. The solutions was to load the scripts in ok.html file. I dont exactly know why it works now because i had already tried this. but it works for now !

Comment: Glad to hear. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if you believe it helped you solve the problem :-) I'm sure it was just a `CORS` issue.

Comment: Yeah, i've read a bit about CORS issues and this does seem to be the problem. but it is solved now! thanks for your help !